Is there any closed form expression of the sum $\sum\limits_{m = 0}^{n} \frac {\Gamma (a + m)} {m!} \frac{\Gamma (b + n - m)}{(n-m)!}$ for $a, b>0.$

Is there any closed form expression of the sum $$\sum\limits_{m = 0}^{n} \frac {\Gamma (a + m)} {m!} \frac {\Gamma (b + n - m)} {(n - m)!}$$ for $a, b > 0\ $?

I am currently working with a power series which involves sum of the above form and hence I would like to know whether there is a closed form expression of the sum. Any suggestion would be appreciated.
Thanks and Regards
Akiro.

Unrolling the Gamma function we get
$$\Gamma(a) \Gamma(b)
\sum_{m=0}^n {a+m-1\choose m} {b+n-m-1\choose n-m}.$$
This is
$$\Gamma(a) \Gamma(b)
[z^n] \frac{1}{(1-z)^a} \frac{1}{(1-z)^b}
= \Gamma(a) \Gamma(b) {a+b-1+n\choose n}.$$

This looks to be equivalent to the Vandermonde identity under the use of $\binom{r+m-1}{m}=(-1)^m \binom{-r}{m}$.

Yes indeed. Always go for Vandermonde!
